# How to fill remaining div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Well i have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/a9VDa/12/

I am trying to make the jquery tree fill the remaining contents of the div "a" but also include a scroll if there isn't enough space.

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c" id="tree"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make tree fill the remaining contents of div a"? Maybe like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt2sL/1/

Comment: I don't want the orange part scrolling though.

Answer (score 0):

My suggested solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt2sL/2/

- Without orange part scrolling.

**HTML**

```
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="c" id="tree"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px; // adjust this to your need
}

.b {
    height: 22px;
    background-color: coral;
}
.c {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: the 200px in a is the only reason that works... i need "a" to be 100%

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make div b fixed and add some padding to a with overflow scroll set?

```
.a {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-top: 22px;
}

.b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: coral;
}
.c {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```